# How can i make a dynamic layout with fix no. of rows eg 3

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, android-layout

I want a horizontal moving layout with 3 rows and any no. of columns depending on the number of items fetched from the server. Gridview does set no. of columns but i want to fix no. of rows.

I am specifying a link for the exact layout i want.
https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/wassup-b21d5.appspot.com/o/Picture.png?alt=media&token=889a2c74-9d43-4557-8d5e-8ded80212d1e

Answer (score 0):

Use RecyclerView with GridLayoutManager. When you create a horizontal GridLayoutManager and set spanCount, it's considered as number of rows and not columns.

```
recyclerView.layoutManager = GridLayoutManager(requireContext(), 3, HORIZONTAL, false)
```

If you're not familiar with RecyclerView see [this](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/recyclerview) and [this](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/recyclerview-custom).

Comment: Thanks, There is one more thing as you can see in the image , i have to place the objects alternatively so how will the xml file look like?

Comment: Are you talking about white space between items? You can consider two view types for your adapter. A ViewGroup that contains an ImageView and a TextView, and another view that is nothing but just a View with white background. Then in your adapter you can decide which of these two view types should be used for a certain position. For example when position is even then use the first view type and when it's odd use the second one. See this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26245139/how-to-create-recyclerview-with-multiple-view-type. If the answer helped you please mark it as accepted.